# import odt document to another odt document

Tags: java, templates, openoffice.org

what's the best way of copying a whole odt file to another existing odt file using java-API?

I'm allready using the simple-odf-toolkit for manipulating odt files, but I can't figure out how to 'import' another file.

regards